# Extract domain from the string

Tags: java, dns, extract

What's the best way to extract the domain name from the string?

Eg. `xyz.com/path1/path2/path3/somefile.txt`

As there's no protocol, cannot use `java.net.URL`.

The only option I can think of is to read till first forward slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply prefix `http://` to that string and construct a `URL` object and extract the host name using the `getHost()` method.

```
String urlString = "xyz.com/path1/path2/path3/somefile.txt";
URL url = new URL("https://" + urlString);
System.out.println(url.getHost());
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun, OP seems to be saying that since the string doesn't have a protocol (like http/https), URL construction fails with that message. But since he is just interested in extracting host name and other components of the URL, he can simply append some protocol and leverage the URL's apis, right?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there will never be an http:// to add extra slashes, you could do this:

```
String domain = urlString.substring(0, urlString.indexOf("/"));
```

That will give you a substring up to the first slash.

edit: 
As pointed out, this will fail if there are no slashes. You could fix that like this:

```
int index = urlString.indexOf("/");
if(index >= 0) String domain = urlString.substring(0, index);
```

But you're really better off using Quoi's solution if there may be no slashes in your input.

Comment: This will fail if the `String` is (for example): *stackoverflow.com* (With no `/')

Answer (score 1):

you can use `String#split` with regx - '`/`'

```
String[] split = str.split("/");
System.out.println(split[0]);
```